# OMNEST used to work fine but for the last few days it showed java heap space error

Tags: java, omnet++

My OMNEST was working fine for many years until the last few days when it showed error about java heap space. I listed below some errors that I saw
1. An internal error occurred during: "EnclosingASTNameJob".
Java heap space
2. An internal error occurred during: "Computing Macro Expansion".
Java heap space
As far I remember, I did not install any new program nor changed any Java related config. FYI, I am not familiar with Java
I will appreciate any help
thanks
Gaza